# R: getting list of matching data frame values

Tags: r, rdata

Two data sets:

```
people <- read.table(text="
pid
1
2
3
4
", header=TRUE)

comps <- read.table(text="
pid comp rank
1   1    0
1   3    1
1   2    2
2   4    0
2   1    1
2   3    2
3   1    0
3   2    1
3   4    2
", header=TRUE)
```

Trying to get a data frame of each unique `pid` with a list of their comparisons, like:

```
pid comps
1   1,3,2
2   4,1,3
3   1,2,4
```

Can't quite get there..

Comment: `data[,.(value=paste(value,collapse="")),by=group]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(comp~pid, comps, paste, collapse=",")
#   pid  comp
# 1   1 1,3,2
# 2   2 4,1,3
# 3   3 1,2,4
```

Comment: Excellent. Is there a way to add a third column?

Comment: @Wells sure, just return a vector, e.g. `aggregate(comp~pid, comps, function(x) c(paste(x, collapse=","), "A"))`